# Stop showing dialog box after pressing back

Tags: android, android-dialog

Ok, so I have 3 activities (A, B, C) Activity A being the main activity.
In Activity A, I have a password dialog box and a button (button that leads to activity B).

So, when I open my app, the password dialog box will appear. Now my problem is that, whenever I'm in activity B and I press back button that leads to activity A, the password dialog box keeps appearing. What I want is, the password dialog box will only appear if I open my app and not if I go back to activity A from activity B.

**Activity B**

```
public void onBackPressed() {

        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(Form.this);
        adb.setTitle("Go back to Activity A?"); 
        adb.setCancelable(false);
        adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        adb.setPositiveButton("Exit", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class));
            }
        });
        adb.show();
    }
```

In my activity B, I have a button (button that leads to activity C). That's why I setup the onBackPressed in activity B.

**Activity A**

```
public void toB(View view) {    
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: In onBackPressed(), which is in ActivityB, when user clicks Exit, it should take him/her to ActivityA, yes?

Comment: Also, do you WANT to be able to go to ActivityA from ActivityB? Please update your question with Activity A code.

Comment: yes. I've updated my code. It's (ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class) not (ActivityB.this, ActivityB.class)

Comment: 1. When you call ActivityB in ActivityA, do you close ActivityA? 2. If you call ActivityC from ActivityB, where do you want to go if you press back in ActivityC, to B or A? 3. Show your code for ActivityA.

Comment: There you go. Pressing back in my activity c will lead to my activity B.

Comment: Solved it. I tried the answers below. But I used a simplier solution. changing startActivity(new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class)); to finish();

Comment: Ha, was just writing an answer which suggests just that :) This way you're letting Android handle the navigation, which is the correct thing to do in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy. All you have to do when going back to Activity A from Activity B is to tell Activity A that you're coming from Activity B.

In your `onBackPressed()`, replace `startActivity(new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityB.class));` with the following code :

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("from", "activityB");
```

Then, in Activity A, just check for this extra before displaying the dialog box :

```
Intent thisIntent = getIntent();
if (thisIntent != null && thisIntent.getExtras() != null
        && thisIntent.getExtras().containsKey("from")
        && thisIntent.getExtras().getString("from").equals("activityB")) {
        // Coming from Activity B : nothing
} else {
    // Display your dialog box
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it and it worked. I tried also changing startActivity(new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class)); to finish(); and it also worked.

Comment: Glad it helped! If you put startActivity(new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class)) instead of finish(), you're sure that the app will go to ActivityA when exiting, especially if you have a complicated navigation between activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a flag through the bundlesavedinstance to notify activity A that it's being called from activity B

Comment: where do I put that flag? In activity A or B?

Comment: you put an extra in activityB calling activityA, then you try to get it in activityA. If you can, then the caller is activityB and you do nothing. Else, if it doesn't exist, then the app has just opened and you display the message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry if I can't +1 your comment now. I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've accepted an answer, here are some points to keep in mind.

Your navigation stacks might be:

- A -> B -> pressing Back -> A
- A -> B -> C -> pressing Back -> B -> pressing Back -> A

Why don't let Android handle this for you? How? Because you're not finishing A, its' onPause() is called when you start B. Now in B, when pressing Back button, just call finish(), instead of using an Intent to go to A. That way, provided that your password dialog is in onCreate() in A, A's onResume() will be called and dialog won't be displayed.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    adb.setTitle("Go back to Activity A?"); 
    adb.setCancelable(false);
    adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    adb.setPositiveButton("Exit", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //calling finish() will close this Activity(B) and go back to the previous
            //which in your case is Activity A if B was called from A
            finish();
        }
    });
    adb.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. That's what I did. I suspect first that calling startActivity A from B will call the onCreate of A where the dialog box will appear. But from my noobness, I'm thinking too much. I also thought that going from activity B from A will destroy the A. But as you said, it will just be onPause() right?

Answer (score 0):

just add dialog.dismiss(); in your dialog box.
that will solve your problem.